# SpringBoot OpenApi REST controller download zip file even if an exception is thrown

Tags: spring-boot, rest, exception, download, openapi

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.6.13` and, to download a group of file to a `.zip` archive I write the below code following the documentation:

```
@Operation(summary = "Download all attach in a zip by message id.")
  @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Attach downloaded.", content = {
                @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary")) }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "No attach found.", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Error.class)) }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error.", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Error.class)) })
})
@GetMapping("/getMessageAttachs/{id}")
public void getAttachmentsByMessage(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=files.zip";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
    threadAttachmentsService.retrieveMessageFiles(response, id);
}
```

The services `retrieveMessageFiles` do the follows:

```
public void zipFiles(HttpServletResponse response, Integer id) {
    List<ThreadAttachments> attachs = repo.findByMessageId(id); // suppose attachs contains file name and absolute path
    try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {

        for (ThreadAttachments atts : attachs) {
            Path path = Paths.get(atts.getPath(), atts.getNomeFile());
            FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(path);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileSystemResource.getFilename());
            zipEntry.setSize(fileSystemResource.contentLength());
            zipEntry.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

            StreamUtils.copy(fileSystemResource.getInputStream(), zipOutputStream);
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }
        zipOutputStream.finish();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Now if the `nomeFile` and the `path` are in the DB but not in the filesystem the above `IOException` is correctly thrown but, if I test the service from *SwaggerUI* or *Postman*, it still allows me to download an empty zip file.

I tried everything, a custom exception with the `@ControllerAdvice` or putting all controller code inside a `try-catch` block directly but nothing works.

What's wrong?

Comment: Could it be that some of the initial files are in the filesystem so that the exception only arises after some zipfile entries have been streamed to the caller?

Comment: Though you are throwing the exception but you are not returning proper response of your API. Your controller return type is **Void** but it should be **ResponseEntity**. That will solve your problem.